# Finding Dynamic Control (Accordion Pane)

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, accordion

I'm using the code below to create dynamic panes in an accordion control. Info is read from a data set and the controls are generated based on that info. I'm now stuck when it comes to finding these controls. When a user clicks a button I need to loop through all the controls and get the information inside the textboxes... but all I really need to know is how to call the darn things!

```
        Do Until b = 0
            holder = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Issue" & z).ToString
            If holder <> "" Then
                lblTitle = New Label()
                txtContent = New TextBox()
                lblTitle.Text = "Issue" & z & " " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Issue" & z)
                txtContent.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Issue" & z)
                pn = New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane()
                pn.ID = "Pane" & z
                pn.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lblTitle)
                pn.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(txtContent)
                arcPane.Panes.Add(pn)

            End If
            pncount = pncount + 1
            z = z + 1
            b = b - 1
        Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Every control has a property called Controls, which is a collection of immediate child controls. Looping through them is possible, where you can examine them one by one until you find the one that you want. Each control instance also has a method called FindControl, which you can use to look up controls by their IDs. You should be able to find them this way. Start from the first common parent control (e.g. arcPane).

```
foreach (Control pane in arcPane.Panes)
{
    foreach (Control c in pane.ContentContainer.Controls)
    {
        //examine c.ClientID or c.GetType() or some other 
                    //property that you can recognize the control by
    }
}
```

Comment: Still having difficulties finding. Might be in my C to VB conversion (not very good at that!).

Comment: This wont work because the control are cleared from the Accordion over postback since they were dynamically created.  Hence, arcPane.Panes.Count will be 0